# TikZ: Draw under base line and keep the normal spacing between lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, vspace, baseline

### Problem

I want to achieve a command for tied lyrics like in lilypond. Now I have it nearly working, but the downside is, that the tikz picture effects the spacing between the lines, which adds too much extra space, which makes the overall text look not good.

### MWE

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\tie}[1]{%
    {\hspace*{-0.5ex}\tikz[baseline=(a.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt] (a) {#1};
        \node[below=-1ex of a,outer sep=0pt] (b) {\resizebox{\widthof{#1} * \real{0.85}}{1ex}{\rotatebox{90}{$\Bigl($}}};
    }}%
}%

\begin{document}
First, to show the normal line spacing: \lipsum[1]
When \tie{this is} called, additional space is added between the lines, but I want to keep the original white space,
even if that means, that the tie touches the letters in the next line. In the next line \tie{it's called} \tie{two times}.
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

### Example image

In the following image, we can clearly see that the space between the lines looks bad in exactly two lines, where I have put the tikz code. I want to have the same white space between the lines here, too. Even if that means, that the drawing touches or overdraws the next line.

[image: tikz: draw under baseline]

Note, that I can't use a solution to the problem that would use `addvspace`, because later I'm using the code inside a list, where `addvspace` does not work.

Comment: Add `overlay` as an option to the second node.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, that solves the problem. Do you want to add this as an answer? Otherwise, I can also write the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with every node, even the `b` node will contribute to the bounding box of the TikZpicture. The whole picture is then too deep to fit in the normal line.

With the [option `overlay`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/overlay) you can instruct TikZ not to consider the node (or whatever you use it on) to contribute to the bounding box. This is very similar to the macros `\llap`, `\lrap` and `\smash` basically.

I've added `\Tie`, another way to define this command with only TikZ, no `positioning` and no `calc` package since TikZ comes with PGFmath. (We could also just measure the node with `#1` in it and use that for the scaling but that needs a bit more work than `width("#1")`.)

Here I set all inner and outer seps to zero so that the node will fit tightly into the text. The node for the `(` is done as a label where we can reference the parent node directly (here `south:` specifies the south anchor of the parent node).

At the end of the document I use both options on top of each other to show the difference.

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\Tie}[1]{% no calc package and no positioning library
  \tikz[inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt,baseline=+0pt]
    \node[anchor=base, label={[%
        overlay, anchor=east, yshift=+-.1ex,
        rotate=90, xscale=.8,
        yscale={.85*width("#1")/(height("{$\Bigl($}")+depth("{$\Bigl($}"))}
      ] south:$\Bigl($}]{#1};%
}%
\newcommand{\tie}[1]{%
    {\hspace*{-0.5ex}\tikz[baseline=(a.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt] (a) {#1};
        \node[overlay,below=-1ex of a,outer sep=0pt] (b) {\resizebox{\widthof{#1} * \real{0.85}}{1ex}{\rotatebox{90}{$\Bigl($}}};
    }}%
}%

\begin{document}
First, to show the normal line spacing: \lipsum[1]
When \tie{this is} called, additional space is added between the lines, but I want to keep the original white space,
even if that means, that the tie touches the letters in the next line. In the next line \tie{it's called} \tie{two times}.
\lipsum[1]

First, to show the normal line spacing: \lipsum[1]
When \Tie{this is} called, additional space is added between the lines, but I want to keep the original white space,
even if that means, that the tie touches the letters in the next line. In the next line \tie{it's called} \Tie{two times}.
\lipsum[1]

{\pgfsetfillopacity{.5}%
       \color{blue}x\tie{two times}x%
  \llap{\color{red}x\Tie{two times}x}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I improved my code in the mean time, to fit also special cases like "deep letters" like a "p" and prevent line breaks within ties. I will add my answer also.

Comment: @Guest Line breaks won't happen inside a TikZpicture. Letters with descendenders probably needs a carefully selected `text depth` value? Or maybe a different kind of parenthesis? Not much space to work with then.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help by [Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel), I added the `overlay` option to my previous code to fix the main problem, and also found out that `below=someDimension of nodeName.base` can be used in TikZ to define the perfect y coordinate. Then, also words containing deep letters like `p` and `g` have the tie at the base line height.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\tie}[1]{\mbox{\hspace*{-0.5ex}\tikz[baseline=(a.base)]{%
    \node[inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt] (a) {#1};%
    \node[below=-0.5ex of a.base,outer sep=0pt,overlay] (b) {\resizebox{\widthof{#1} * \real{0.9}}{0.5ex}{\rotatebox{90}{$\Bigl($}}};%
}\hspace*{-0.5ex}}}

\begin{document}
First, to show the normal line spacing: \lipsum[1]
When \tie{this is} called, \tie{additional space} is added between the lines, but I want to keep the original white space,
even if that means, that the tie touches the letters in the next line. In the next line \tie{it's called} \tie{two times}.
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]